# In hadoop - Map-Reduce error with filesplit

Tags: hadoop

When I use the below lines in map class:

```
String fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
System.out.println(fileName);
```

I got an empty output file. Also, the last two lines in console are:

```
14/05/06 12:52:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=0
14/05/06 12:52:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=2127
```

Comment: Your question doesn't contain a question. Try to improve it.

Comment: My problem is that i don't get back the names of the files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `System.out.println()`, you will not get the result in the console. You need to check your logs.

Or much easier: use a logger !

1. Import classes needed for logging

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
   import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
   ```
2. Define the logger

   ```
   private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
   ```
3. Log all what you need

   ```
   LOG.info(fileName);
   ```

You will get the results during the job execution in the console.

Comment: I used the System.out in order to see if i take correctly the name of input File... Finally, i found my mistake... Thanks for your answers!